# Evaluate $\lim_{n\to \infty}{\sqrt[n]\frac{(2n)!}{n^n\times{n!}}}$

Tags: limits

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}{\sqrt[n]\frac{(2n)!}{n^n\times{n!}}}$$

It is a sequence and n is natural

It looks like I should use $\lim_{n\to \infty}{\sqrt[n]{a_n}}=x$ but I don't know how. Does it mean that $a_n=\frac{(2n)!}{n^n\times{n!}}$ and then do it from there or is $a_n=\sqrt[n]\frac{(2n)!}{n^n\times{n!}}$

I have never used this before and I am not sure what to do

Comment: Try to use Stirling approximation:

$$n! \approx \sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n$$

With $n \to 2n$ in your case

Comment: That's too strong. You only need $(n!)^{1/n} \approx n/e$ (as poorly stated in my answer).

Answer (score 4):

Let $a_n = \dfrac{(2n)!}{n^n{n!}}$. Then
$\displaystyle
\lim_{n\to \infty}{\sqrt[n]{a_n}}
=
\lim_{n\to \infty}\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}
$
if this limit exists.

Now
$$
\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}
=
\dfrac{(2(n+1))!}{(n+1)^{n+1}{(n+1)!}}
\
\dfrac{n^n{n!}}{(2n)!}
=
\dfrac{(2n+2)(2n+1)}{(n+1)(n+1)}
\
\left(\dfrac{n}{n+1}\right)^n
\to
\dfrac{4}{e}
$$

Comment: Nice use of the limits. Glad that my answer agrees with yours.

Comment: I realised that I was using the theorem incorrectly. I got this also, thanks for confirmation.

Answer (score 3):

Since
$\lim_{n \to \infty} (n!)^{1/n}
\approx (n/e)
$,

$\begin{array}\\
\lim_{n\to \infty}{\sqrt[n]\frac{(2n)!}{n^n\times{n!}}}
&=\lim_{n\to \infty}{\frac{((2n)!)^{1/n}}{n(n!)^{1/n}}}\\
&\approx\frac{\lim_{n\to \infty}((2n)!)^{1/n)}}{n(n/e)}\\
&=\frac{\lim_{n\to \infty}(((2n)!)^{1/(2n)})^2}{n(n/e)}\\
&\approx\frac{(2n/e)^2}{n(n/e)}\\
&=\frac{4}{e}
\end{array}
$

You can make it more general
and use
$\lim_{n \to \infty} ((kn)!)^{1/n}
=\lim_{n \to \infty} (((kn)!)^{1/(kn)})^k
=(kn/e)^k
$
to show that
$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{\frac{(an)!}{n^{cn}(bn)!}}$
exists only when
$a \le b+c$
and is zero when
$a < b+c$
and is
$\frac{a^a}{b^b}e^{b-a}
$
when
$a = b+c$.
The OP is
$a=2, b = 1, c=1$.

$\begin{array}\\
\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{\frac{(an)!}{n^{cn}(bn)!}}
&\approx\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{(an/e)^a}{n^c(bn/e)^b}\\
&=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{a^a}{b^b}e^{b-a}n^{a-b-c}\\
\end{array}
$

and this exists as stated.

Note:
If you want to
make this more rigorous,
and use
$\frac{(n!)^{1/n}}{n}
\approx \frac1{e}
$,
and similarly use
$\frac{(kn)!^{1/n}}{n^k}
=\frac{((kn)!^{1/(kn)})^k}{n^k}
\approx\frac{(kn/e)^k}{n^k}
=(k/e)^k
$

you can write

$\begin{array}\\
\sqrt[n]{\frac{(an)!}{n^{cn}(bn)!}}
&=\frac{\frac{((an)!)^{1/n}}{n^a}}{\frac{((bn)!)^{1/n}}{n^b}}
\frac{n^a}{n^{c}n^b}\\
&\approx\frac{(a/e)^a}{(b/e)^b}n^{a-b-c}\\
&=\frac{a^a}{b^b}e^{b-a}n^{a-b-c}\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: "$\lim_{n\to\infty}(n!)^{1/n}=(n/e)$" is an odd way of specifying the asymptotics, since the RHS isn't independent of $n$; I know exactly what you mean, but I've never seen that phrasing before (I usually see something like "Since $(n!)^{1/n}\approx(n/e)$ as $n\to\infty$"). Is it a common idiom?

Comment: Yeah, sometimes I get imprecise, but I know what I mean and I am pretty sure that my answer is correct.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that it is too, FWIW.

Comment: I changed it to use $\approx$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint :** Use Cauchy's second limit theorem.

If $\displaystyle \lim_n\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=l$ , then $\displaystyle \lim_na_n^{1/n}=l$. Where , $\displaystyle a_n=\frac{(2n)!}{n^2.n!}$.

Comment: but what is $a_n$? the original function? because then I will have a square root of a square root?

Comment: Using this formula and the suggestion from kim I now have ${\frac{2^n\times\sqrt{2}}{n^2}}^\frac{1}{n}$

Comment: It should read as the whole fraction to the power 1/n

Comment: @babylon) Only use any **one** technique. Don't mix them .  Either you use only my hint. or use kim's hint.

Comment: but if I use your hint there is nothing I can do? I have ${\frac{(2n)!}{n^2\times{n!}}}^\frac{1}{n}$ i don't see how this can lead me to a solution :( @S.Panja-1729